# Unable to run this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, qsqlquery

```
SELECT MIN(DATE) as START_DATE,
       MAX(DATE) as END_DATE, 
       datediff(day, START_DATE, END_DATE) AS DURATION
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

I'm getting this error while executing the above query. Can somebody please help me to solve this. I'm trying to get the start date, end date and duration between them.

> Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: Have you checked [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)?

Comment: In MySQL DATEDIFF() function has 2 parameters.

Comment: What kind of difference should that query return?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(DATE) as START_DATE,MAX(DATE) as END_DATE, 
datediff(MIN(DATE), MAX(DATE)) AS DURATION 
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in  your code:

- You are using `datediff()` with three arguments.  That is a SQL Server function, not a MySQL function.
- Second, you are using column aliases as arguments to the function.  That is not allowed.

Also, you need to remember that the arguments to `datediff()` start with the *bigger* value in MySQL, not the smaller.  So:

```
select min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date,
       datediff(max(date), min(date)) as duration
from customer;
```